# Django - Selecting related set : how many times does it hit the database?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-orm

I took this sample code here : [Django ORM: Selecting related set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853184/django-orm-selecting-related-set)

```
polls = Poll.objects.filter(category='foo')
choices = Choice.objects.filter(poll__in=polls)
```

My question is very simple : do you hit twice the database when you finally use the queryset `choices` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be one query, but containing an inner `SELECT`; if you want to do some debugging on that, you could either use the marvellous [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar), or do something like `print str(choices.query)` which will output the raw sql of your query!

Comment: Oh yeah ... I have heard once or twice about this `.query`, but I always forget ...

Thanks for the answer !